# Center text under image inside a container with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to get text be centered along with an image, using flexbox. The text is aligned properly, but not the corresponding images.

CSS:

```
body { font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
       display: flex; 
       flex-direction: column; 
       align-items: center; 
       justify-content: center; }

.infoheader { font-size: 36px;
              font-weight: 300;
              margin-bottom: 12px;
              text-align: center; }

.body { display: flex; 
        gap: 10px; 
        text-align: center; 
        justify-content: center; }

.card { max-width: 200px; }

.fishes { height: 100px; 
          width: 100px; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="infoheader">An Example Assortment of Fishes:</div>
    <div class="body">
         <div class="card">
            <img class="fishes" src="./fishes/onefish.jpg" alt="funny fish">
            <div class="text">what would  happen if i added a very very very long line    of text</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img class="fishes" src="./fishes/bluefish.jpg" alt="funny fish">
            <div class="text">This is some subtext under an image.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img class="fishes" src="./fishes/fish.jpg" alt="SEAL">
            <div class="text">This is some subtext under an image.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img class="fishes" src="./fishes/twofish.jpg" alt="funny fish">
            <div class="text">This is some subtext under an image.</div>
          </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

By adding

```
justify-content: center;
text-align: center
```

to .body, I thought that the image and text would be centered with each other, but only the text is centered and the images look like they are displaying slightly to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the `.card` class as follows:

```
.card {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you! I did not think to align vertically within in the card with flex: column.

Comment: You are welcome. Am glad the solution worked.